# Asterisks on Password for Bash Shell (or ssh?)

Tags: macos, bash

When I do certain operations (in the terminal on OSX) I am prompted for a password, and there are never any asterisks to see where I am. Is there any way to get asterisks? I realize that it's a security hole, but lack-of-usability is also a problem.

Some examples are:

- Running commands that require sudo
- ssh to another machine that requires a password

Comment: Why is it a lack-of-usability?

Comment: @crasic, to reverse the question, why do Windows and OSX and ALL web applications show visual feedback as you type a password? It's more usable.

Answer (score 3):

Not without rewriting the programs themselves. And it's not exactly a trivial change either.

Comment: A quick troll through the man pages `stty (1)`, `tty (4)`, `getpass (3)`, and `readpassphrase (3)` seems to confirm this.

Comment: `sudo` has an option `visiblepw` for this.

Comment: @grawity: As that is directly responsive to one part of the question you should probably make it an answer.

Comment: @grawity, that's not in `man sudo`. Where can I read about that? Thanks.

Comment: @Yar: It's in `sudoers(5)`. @grawity: That doesn't make `sudo` show the password, it only allows `sudo` to work in situations where it *can't* make the password invisible.

Comment: @Ignacio: It's `pwfeedback` then, not `visiblepw` - sorry. I apparently was reading a bit too fast.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, @grawity, here it is for OSX http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/sudoers.5.html but `pwfeedback` is not mentioned. Also, what should the sudoers file look like?

Comment: @Yar: Apparently `pwfeedback` was added in *sudo* 1.8.0; the OS X manual is for 1.7.0.

Comment: @grawity, thanks, but how would one do this? I played with my sudoers file a bit this morning, but put it back right before major system meltdown and getting locked out of sudo.

Comment: @Yar: `Defaults pwfeedback` to set it globally. (Tip: When playing with such configurations, keep around a few terminals with `sudo -s` running in them.)